# Rails and Devise - Access session data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I have a Rails app with devise integrated. I'm using the Cookie Store session. I need to store some data in the session everytime someone signs in, Eg. their user id. How can i do so with Devise?

May be there is some elegant way where i just dont need to do that and could access it with Devise itself.?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the "session" variable inside the controllers. Something like 
 `session[:some_value] = "some_value"`

Also Devise already has the user_id stored in the session.`current_user` helper method can be used here.

Also make sure you read this, it has details about the what to store in session or not.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Also cookie session store is usually only 4k in size, so you can't store a lot of data in them or your app will start to error out.

Comment: This does not work for me. Even when logged in, my session is nil. Any other ideas?

Comment: How to get information as when a session is going to expire?